# How to add dropdown list with textbox in bootstrap that select the option from dropbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to add dropdown list within textbox that should select the option from the list.

I found the html to but its not select the option, but redirecting to page.
The html code is below.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data- toggle="dropdown">Domain<span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">@gmail.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">@yahoo.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">@hotmail.com</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you want, but if you don't want it to redirect, don't use the <a> tag. Just put the text in the <li> tag.

Comment: I did the same. but its not replace Domain to what I select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that you want to pick a `@domain` and change the button text.

I made use of `<select>` and `<option>` html tags, and some jQuery.

Your solution is here : https://jsfiddle.net/urahara/qtr7hgn7/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Domain<span class="caret"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
                    <option>@gmail.com</option>
                    <option>@yahoo.com</option>
                    <option>@hotmail.com</option>
                </select>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </input>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            $('button').html( $(this).text() );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I already have this. But i need it to bootstrap grouped with text box.

Comment: the system will accept only three kind of email address. that is "gmail.com", "yahoo.com" and "hotmail.com". User will type the user_name and will select the domain.

Comment: Well what is wrong with the solution I provided? You can write your `username` and select a `domain`, that will be added to your `username`..

Comment: I apply you code. Its going same as <li>. That is not replacing "Domain" with what i select from list

Comment: OK, now I understand. You want to change the button `domain` text as you select the @domain. I have updated my answer check it out.

Comment: @Piotr Dajlido If you want to add caret after selection then add this in your code:                                                                                                                     `$('button').html( $(this).text()+'<span class="caret"></span>' );`